# how to get value ng-model in html to javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, web, parse-platform

Probably silly question, but I have my html form with simple input and password:

```
<li>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="user.username" />
  <a class="iconani usera"></a>
</li>
<li>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.password" />
  <a class="iconani locka"></a>
</li>
```

and i want to get value from ng-model to java script

```
query.equalTo("user", document.getElementById('value from ng-model'));
```

I use this from parse.com
Can you help me?

Comment: use $scope.user.username AND $scope.user.password

Comment: @MatejŽvan Not working sir :(

Answer (score 1):

In AngularJS, you don't need (and want) to touch your DOM at all to get the data. `ng-model` directive creates an automated two-way binding between your `<input>` and your `$scope.user` variable's properties.

```
login($scope.user.username, $scope.user.password, ...);
```

You don't need to touch the form itself at all.

Comment: You need to provide a jsfiddle/codepen then, to show the relation between the two pieces of code you've included so far.

Comment: angular.module('AuthApp', [])
 .run(['$rootScope', function($scope) {
   $scope.scenario = 'Log in';
   $scope.currentUser = Parse.User.current();
   
   $scope.logIn = function(form) {
  Parse.User.logIn(form.username, form.password, {
    success: function(user) {
   $scope.currentUser = user;
   $scope.$apply();
    },
    error: function(user, error) {
   alert(error.message);
    }
  });
   };
   
   $scope.logOut = function(form) {
  Parse.User.logOut();
  $scope.currentUser = null;
   };

Comment: I've updated my answer to make it clearer (hopefully). The important part is: **do not touch the form in your JS code**, just use `$scope`.

Answer (score 0):

hon2a's answer is the right one ;-) I can try to explain it a bit differently as I also just recently started using angular. A good and simple intro to angular concepts of ng-model and controllers is given at http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_intro.asp.

So, all your javascript should be executing in Angular Controllers. In the corresponding controller (i.e. javascript code) the data from HTML form is bound using that angular directive "ng-model" and nothing else. You have your HTML part just fine, assuming you have the angular stuff somewhere linked properly (I would strongly recommend using Yeoman Angular generator to handle that...). At least there should be something like this:

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="yourApp" ng-controller="yourController">
    <!-- your app part goes here -->
</div>
```

And then the in the angular controller you actually have that data at hand automatically without doing anything else than just having a constructor/initialiser for it:

```
angular.module('yourApp').controller('yourController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.user = {'username': '', 'userpassword': ''};

    // And rest of your stuff goes here...
    // In your functions, just use $scope.user.username and $scope.user.userpassword. 
}
```

Hope this helps...